# How to compare Array value to result of 'for' loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an empty array (called zoomthumbsarray) which gets values pushed to it whilst a 'for' loop is running. This 'for' loop is checking if a thumbnail image is present in the backend against the particular product the user is viewing. If there is an image it gets added into a vertical slider. The current issue is there are non colour specific images (like lifestyle shots) that are being added into the slider multiple times.

So I need to check if the image found in the for loop is currently stored in the array. If it is present, the image has already been generated and I don't want it to get pulled into the slider again. If it hasn't then the image will get added.

Below is the code I am working on. I would presume indexOf would be used but can't get this to work.

Any help would be really appreciated.

```
var zoomthumbsarray = [] // Empty array which gets populated by .push below during loop

for (var i = 0; i < storeImgsArr.length; i++) { // storeImgsArr finds the quantity of attributes present against the product. This loops and increments counter if there is another attibute image
    for (var e = 0; e < storeImgsArr[i].images.imgL.length; e++) { // Loop and increment counter if there is a Large image 

        zoomthumbsarray.push(storeImgsArr[i].images.imgS[e].slice(-16)); // Slices off last 16 characters of image path i.e. _navy_xsmall.jpg or 46983_xsalt1.jpg and pushes this into 'zoomthumbsarray' array

        // if statement sits here to build the html to add the image to the slider

    }
}

zoomthumbsarray = [] // Resets array to zero
```

**ANSWER**
As answered by Chris I used $.unique to only keep unique values in the array.
Then wrap an if statement around the code to build the thumb image html if the array === 0 or if the current image isn't already in the array.

Updated code below:

```
var zoomthumbsarray = [] // Empty array which gets populated by .push below during loop

for (var i = 0; i < storeImgsArr.length; i++) { // storeImgsArr finds the quantity of attributes present against the product. This loops and increments counter if there is another attibute image

    if (zoomthumbsarray === 0 || zoomthumbsarray.indexOf(storeImgsArr[i].images.imgS[e].slice(-16)) < 0) { // If statement is true if array === 0 or if the current image isn't already in the array 

        for (var e = 0; e < storeImgsArr[i].images.imgL.length; e++) { // Loop and increment counter if there is a Large image 

            zoomthumbsarray.push(storeImgsArr[i].images.imgS[e].slice(-16)); // Slices off last 16 characters of image path i.e. _navy_xsmall.jpg or 46983_xsalt1.jpg and pushes this into 'zoomthumbsarray' array

            zoomthumbsarray = $.unique(zoomthumbsarray); //Keeps only unique elements

            // if statement sits here to build the html to add the image to the slider

        }
    }
}
```

zoomthumbsarray = [] // Resets array to zero

Comment: `indexOf` returns `-1` if not found or an index, not `true|false`

Comment: @elclanrs Thanks I've actually edited the question and removed my attempt of indexOf as hacked about with it so much it's probably misleading. Question still stands at how I would achieve comparing value in array to value in for loop.

Comment: @Chris The $.unique worked perfectly! Thanks for that little gem. Just had to add a new if statement around the second for loop to incorporate this and job done! Thanks all for your comments

Comment: @Damodog glad to help! What's with zoomthumbsarray === 0?

Comment: @chris The array is empty on the first iteration of the code so I have this present just for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some cheap and dirty ideas:

Using [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/)/[lodash](http://lodash.com/):

```
zoomthumbsarray = _.uniq(zoomthumbsarray); //Keeps only unique elements
```

jQuery [has one](http://api.jquery.com/category/utilities/) as well:

```
zoomthumbsarray = $.unique(zoomthumbsarray); //Keeps only unique elements
```

then you loop through the array and build HTML.

*Update*:
There's something a bit odd about the rest of the JS. Might this work (if you're using a new enough browser)?

```
var zoomthumbsarray = [];
storeImgsArr
    .map(function(item) { return item.images.imgS; })
    .forEach(function(imgS) {
        zoomthumbsarray = zoomthumbsarray.concat(imgS.map(function(imagePath) {
            return imagePath.slice(-16);
        }));
    });
zoomthumbsarray = $.unique(zoomthumbsarray);
```

Comment: (Nitpicker's note: If performance matters (and it shouldn't if you're just running this once per page), an object/keys model has the potential to be faster. It probably won't be, but it could be. JSPerf is the only way to settle these debates for sure.)

Comment: Instead of udnerscore maybe lodash ?

Comment: @skmasq sure, it would look exactly the same. I haven't heard of lodash before - thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I think you misinterpreted me, [loadsh](http://lodash.com/) in majority functions is faster than underscore. And in many features have more functionality available.

Comment: @Chris: Where would you put the `unique` call in the OP's code?

Comment: @skmasq what I meant to say is that the syntax for unique is the same, not the performance or other features.

Comment: @Bergi at the end, to remove duplicates. Then you build the HTML all at once and reset zoomthumbsarray.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using an array you can use an object to store the images as keys and a dummy value (possibly true). then you can extract the keys from this object.

```
var images = {};

for (var i = 0; i < storeImgsArr.length; i++) { 
    for (var e = 0; e < storeImgsArr[i].images.imgL.length; e++) { 
        images[storeImgsArr[i].images.imgS[e].slice(-16))] = true; 
    }
}
var zoomthumbsarray = [];
for(var k in images) {
    zoomthumbsarray.push(k);
    // build the html to add the image to the slider
}
```

EDIT: Added build html comment

Comment: Please also suggest where to put the `// statement to build the html`, since this need a little modification compared to OP's structure.

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried indexOf (see first if statement below) but this doesn't work.

As @elclanrs said, [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) does return the index in the array not a boolean. You only will need to see if it's `>= 0` to test whether an image is already contained in the array.

```
var zoomthumbsarray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < storeImgsArr.length; i++) {
    for (var e = 0; e < storeImgsArr[i].images.imgL.length; e++) {
        var image = storeImgsArr[i].images.imgS[e].slice(-16);

        if (zoomthumbsarray.indexOf(image) < 0) { // not yet in the array
            zoomthumbsarray.push();
            // and build the html to add the image to the slider
        }
    }
}
```

If you have really lots of images and notice this starts slowing the page down, then there are too many images in your page anyway. No, joke aside; …then check the optimisation by @Ivey.